# Browse archived website

Tags: zip, webpage, webarchive

I have html/webpage files stored in a folder locally on my machine. I can view this content just fine using any browser. However, long term, I would prefer to have the contents stored inside of some kind of archive format (ZIP?). I could do this and manually extract the contents each time I want to view the pages. However, this has several disadvantages.

How I can view html/webpage files inside of an archive file with the following conditions:

1. Not having to manually extracted the contents each time
2. The contents should not be extracted into the same directory as the
   archive - it should go somewhere else like a system temp directory
3. Not having to extract ALL the contents just to view a few pages. I
   would like the solution to be able to only extract the contents
   necessary to render the current page being viewed

Comment: With these requirements in mind, why don't you write a script to do that for you?

Comment: @slybloty Why the down vote?

Comment: The downvote wasn't me.

Comment: @slybloty Ah, must have been some coward. Didn't leave a comment.

Comment: I could probably come up with a script to accomplish everything expect item 3. I'm not sure how I could accomplish that? Any ideas?

Comment: The simplest way to accomplish item 3 would be having your script extract the subdirectory your page is in plus the images and CSS directories. That should extract most of the things included in any given page while cutting down on the unnecessary files extracted. (Upvoted to counter the downvote, btw)

Answer (score 3):

The one way, that I can think of, to accomplish your requirements would be to write a script that does this. When you want to see a page from the archive, open it with the script.

This way, you can have the script do the following:

- create a temporary folder
- read the `HTML` file
- grab all the links needed
- go through them and grab the rest of links, if any
- create the structure from the archive
- extract the needed files (from links) into the newly created structure
- display the page
- remove the temp folder upon closing the page

I know it involves a little bit of work, but, depending on the usage and necessity it might be worth it.